# How to change volume of key click?

Tags: java, android

I need to modify the volume of key clicks (not music).

I tried this:

```
AudioManager layout = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
layout.setStreamVolume( AudioManager.FX_KEY_CLICK, volumeValue ,0);
```

But it doesn't change it.

I succeeded changing only the music sound, by:

```
AudioManager layout = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
layout.setStreamVolume( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, volumeValue , 0);
```

I found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) that `FX_KEY_CLICK` is responsible for the sound of key clicks. Yet, it's not working for me.

However, **playing** a key click sound *does* work by using `FX_KEY_CLICK`:

```
layout.playSoundEffect( AudioManager.FX_KEY_CLICK, volumeValue );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: FX_ constants are not valid values for setStreamVolume. See AudioManager for a list of STREAM_ constants. It's possible that STREAM_SYSTEM affects click sounds but I doubt it.

<s>According to the documentation for [setStreamVolume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume(int,%20int,%20int)):</s>

"This method has no effect if the device implements a fixed volume policy as indicated by isVolumeFixed()"

This was added in Lollipop. It's there because certain manufactures could disallow changing the volume. At first glance, it doesn't seem very likely in your case, but did you try calling it to see what it returns (provided your device runs Lollipop in the first place)?

Comment: `layout.` doesn't have an `isVolumeFixed()` function. It has only: `isBluetoothA2dpON()` , `isBluetoothScoAvailableOffCall()`, `isBluetoothScoOn()` , `isMicrophoneMute()` , `isMusicActive()` , `isSpeakerphoneOne()` , `isWiredHeadsetOn()`. And the device doesn't run Lollipop. It runs gingerbread

Comment: Also, as I mentioned in the question, changing the *Music* sound with setStreamVolume() does work. So I guess volume is not fixed...

Comment: I read sloppy and missed that you passed an invalid stream type. My answer is updated.